# Get AppleScript Path of Parent Folder

Tags: applescript, folders, path

I am writing an AppleScript that will be run from a USB drive, but the dive name may change often so I need to figure out how to get the directory path of the parent folder that contains the script.

This gets me the entire directory with directory to the file, I need the directory of its parent folder:

```
set pPath to path to me as text
display dialog pPath
```

I came across this (which is what I need), but I need an AppleScript path, not a POSIX path!

```
set pPath to POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::")
display dialog pPath
```

When the script is run it should detect the directory path to the script, the first example of code does this, but it then needs to go up one folder to the parent folder which contains the script (the second example does this) but I need it converted from the POSIX path to Applescript path that uses ":" instead of "/".

Comment: I could be wrong however I think you're mixed up a bit in that it appears your using the term `directory` when in reality your mean `path` so I suggest you actually add some real world examples of each element you require because a presently written it is confusing and needs to be edited.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AppleScript is written in English. Read what it says! Remove the `posix path of` from the code, and you'll get the HFS path.

Full code:

```
tell application "Finder" to get (container of (path to me)) as text
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that, however, I get the full path, not the parent path that holds the script.

Comment: I updated it with what you need.

Comment: The code you provided me with seems to work, however, when run from a USB stick, I get the error: Can't make <<class ctnr>> of alias "[path]" into type text. It works when the script is copied to the desktop, but I need to run it from a USB drive.

Comment: @ProGrammer Well, what does your code look like now?

Comment: It uses the code, from your answer, within a directory path. The USB stick has a folder that contains the project's main (exported application) script, along with a resource folder that holds the Installer files I wish to copy. It only works when the folder (main folder) is on the desktop, not when it is on a USB stick, but it should still detect its path (with your code), right? Here is my entire script for you to look at: http://justpaste.it/qwrf

Comment: Try using this modified version, and see what error message you get. Just a heads up: I removed the try blocks. They have the tendency of making debugging code a lot harder, so it's generally best to avoid them. This code should work better. See how it works for you: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/res1233/dummy_repo/master/script.applescript

Comment: I have found out why the folder on the USB stick had to be copied to the desktop, it was because it was sharing the same name as one of the other drives that were connected, so it renamed the new drive to ‘[name] 1’ and the script was looking for the drive without the ‘1’ at the end so of cause it didn’t find any resources on the other drive and threw the error. It runs fine from the USB as long as no other drive is sharing the same name as the USB stick. Thank you for the advice on the try statement.

Comment: Does Finder need to be invoked?

Comment: You don't need Finder for "path to me", but getting its container is a Finder feature. A bit confusing, but c'est la vie.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

**Unix style:**

```
set my_POSIX_path to POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::")
```

If you need to pass it to e.g. shell script, you might want to enclose the path with quotes:

```
set my_POSIX_path to quoted form of POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::")
```

**macOS style:**

```
set my_path to (((path to me as text) & "::") as alias) as string
```

Then depending on your needs, replace `set my_path to / set my_POSIX_path to` with `display dialog` or just `return`.

Comment: This worked beautifully in Script editor in 2023. Thanks